# Node.js mysql2 Wrap joined table into array of objects

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, mysql2

I have faced the problem when I have two tables with relation, let's say **users** and **posts**, and in my DB I have one user with three posts:

Users table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |

Posts table:

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

When i try to retrieve my data with the next SQL query
`this.connection.query(SELECT * FROM users U LEFT JOIN posts.user_id P on U.id = P.user.id`)

i receive three rows for each post with the user:

```js
{ id: 1, name: 'John', posts.id: 1, user_id: 1 }
{ id: 1, name: 'John', posts.id: 2, user_id: 1 }
{ id: 1, name: 'John', posts.id: 2, user_id: 1 }
```

I want to map all joined data into an array of objects, just like this:

```js
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    posts: [
      { id: 1, user_id: 1 },
      { id: 2, user_id: 1 },
      { id: 3, user_id: 1 }, 
    ] 
  } 
]
```

I already implemented my own mapper via the javascript *reduce* method, but I hope this could be done underhood.

Comment: Mysql is a relational database, its response will come in rows and columns. You can write code in mysql to generate a json response formatted according your specification, but that may not be the most efficient solution of all times.

Answer (score 0):

During my investigation, I found [Mysql aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html) documentation. In my case, `JSON_ARRAYAGG` combined with `JSON_OBJECT` did the job for me and returned the result:

```js
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    posts: [
      { id: 1, user_id: 1 },
      { id: 2, user_id: 1 },
      { id: 3, user_id: 1 }, 
    ] 
  } 
]
```

Query, I used to retrieve data:

```
SELECT
  user.id,
  user.name,
  user.age,
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(‘id’, post.id, 'label', post.label)) AS posts
FROM users U
LEFT JOIN posts.user_id P on U.id = P.user.id
GROUP BY U.id
```

Also, this might be useful for **Postgres** users:

```
SELECT
  user.id,
  user.name,
  user.age,
  json_agg(json_build_object('id', post.id, 'label', post.label, ..... )) AS posts
FROM ...
JOIN ...
GROUP  BY user.id, user.name, user.age;
```